# iOS error during test

Tags: ios, unit-testing

I'm trying to test (not to run) my app, but i get the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

and it points to a line in my viewcontroller's initWithNibName.

```
@synthesize messageTextView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
    {
        /*
        some code
        */
     //This is the line where the exception points:
     messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 306, 320, 110)];
        /*
        some other code
        */


    }
    return self;
}
```

My viewcontroller's .h file looks like this:

```
@interface SMMenuViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate ,UITextViewDelegate> 
{
        /*
        some code
        */

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *messageTextView;
```

And i also "nil" messageTextView in viewDidUnload.

I don't know exactly what's wrong, because it works fine when i run it, it only fails during the test.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: What do you think that EXC_BREAKPOINT means? Its a breakpoint! Check the current call stack.

Comment: yes, you're right. the stack points to this line:  messageTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 306, 320, 110)];
I forgot to write it.

Comment: Try `self.messageTextView = [[UITextView ...` in your init method. Tho I'd suggest to do it not in init, maybe later in viewDidLoad.

Comment: i tried and it's not working. i also tried [self setMessageTextView:...] but that's not good either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to alloc/init a view that is referenced as `IBOutlet` (it's automatically instantiated by your xib / storyboard).

Now, what you should really do is to move view customizations inside `viewDidLoad` method, because the view hierarchy is not loaded on `init` (so actually all your views are `nil` by that time). It's loaded when you first try to access one of the views in the hierarchy.

So basically you could do something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.messageTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 306, 320, 110)];
}
```

I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: it does a lot. i used IBOutlet ref. wrong the whole time. the messageTextView is not created with the interface builder, so a removed the IBOutlet and in the .h file it's just simply:
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextView *messageTextView;
and i use the alloc to instantiate the messageTextView in viewDidLoad. Is that the right way then?

Comment: I guess it would be ok then. Just remember to add it as a subview in your main view if you intend to show it somehow...

Comment: i added it. and again, it works fine when it runs, but the same line fails during the test. i have no idea why

Comment: well, unit testing is a bit more complicated. i have to make sure manually that there's an appdelegate object as well. sorry, for trouble and thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: ahhh not working again, i create a new post for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407944/ios-unit-test-run-failure